# Google Spreadsheet adding tooltip

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to add a tooltip (mouser over a cell) in a Google spreadsheet.

I want the tooltip text to be taken from another cell, some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no mouse over event for a spread sheet cell.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Consider using notes - they appear when you hover mouse over cells in a spreadsheet. You can add notes manually by clicking the right mouse button on a cell and selecting 'insert note'. This can also be done programmatically.

Say, you've got 2 adjacent cells. We'll use text from the second cell to add a note to the first one.
[image]

You can create the note with the text from the second cell using the following code.

```
function addNote() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var sourceCell = sheet.getRange("B1");

  var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();

  targetCell.setNote(noteText);

}
```

Here's the end result after executing the function
[image]

You can modify the code to make it run only when the sheet is edited and dynamically update the note when the text in the source cell changes.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the question as resolved if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, I would have preferred a solution that would allow me to modify the style of the note, but it is more than enough and very simple

Comment: I am new to custom functions in google sheets. Can you please tell how to "execute the function". I went to Tools > Script Editor. I then wrote the above code in the editor and saved it. How to "execute/use" this function in the spreadsheet?

Comment: In the dropdown list, select your function and click the 'play' button http://prntscr.com/ibia1f. Please refer to the official GAS documentation on Sheets service. It has lots of examples https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Any keyboard shortcut to add a note?

Comment: Doesn't work to me. "You do not have permission to call setNote (line 14)."

Comment: Getting the same error as @RodrigoAraujo, despite allowing my script access to my sheet. Some more detailed instructions would be great, as otherwise this seems like a really good answer.

Comment: Maybe this has been solved already, but setNote cant really be called. I dont think Google sheets allows you to use custom functions to change cell contents.